# What is the difference between msvcr120.dll and msvcr120_app.dll in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

When I build a Windows Store app using Visual Studio 2013 Preview, I notice that my app binary has a dependency on msvcr120_app.dll.  What is this DLL?  I also noticed that msvcr120_app.dll is not installed in "C:\Windows\System32" whereas msvcr120.dll is installed there.

It's not clear to me

- what is the difference between msvcr120_app.dll and msvcr120.dll?
- how is my app able to run (when I hit F5 in my Visual Studio project) if the dependency msvcr120_app.dll is not installed in System32?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2013, the C++ Runtime DLLs used for Desktop apps are different from those used for Windows Store apps.

- Desktop apps use the runtime DLLs named such as msvcr120.dll, msvcp120.dll, vcamp120.dll, vcomp120.dll, vccorlib120.dll and so on.  Binaries built using the C++ Libs located in “**$(VCInstallDir)lib**" have a dependency on these DLLs.
- Store apps use the runtime DLLs names such as msvcr120_app.dll, msvcp120_app.dll,  vcamp120_app.dll, vcomp120_app.dll and vccorlib120_app.dll.  Binaries built using the C++ Libs located in “**$(VCInstallDir)lib\store**" have a dependency on these DLLs.

The primary difference is that the Store DLLs (those with _app in their names) have been implemented entirely using the Windows API available for Store apps.  This can be verified by running "dumpbin /imports" on both types of DLLs and comparing the results.

Also, the Store DLLs don't need to be installed in System32 because the runtime dependency for Store apps is satisfied using a separate dependency package mechanism [described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx).  One difference between the VCLibs frameworks of VS2012 and VS2013 is that: in Visual Studio 2013 the VCLibs debug AppX package contains both the Debug and Release CRT DLLs.

**Also do note that any Store apps containing any binaries that depend on Desktop C++ Runtime DLLs will not be accepted to the Windows Store.**

Comment: Non-store DLLs do not need to be installed in System32 either. As the name already explains, that directory is part of the (operating) system.

Comment: they don't "need" to be but they can be installed in System32. For good or bad, it has long been the practise to install some runtime DLLs (even non-system ones) into a central directory such as System32.

Comment: Actually those dlls should not be there. Or the app won't pass Microsoft's desktop app certification. The "do not install to system32" policy has been there since Windows 2000.